# what is the content of fsimage, edits log and block reports?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I understood that fsimage is loaded at the time of starting of the services and edits log would be updated with the later transactions. Block reports are those updated to the Namenode's RAM by each and every datanode.

I also understood that fsimage and edits log are persistent on the namenode disk where as the block reports are not persistent.

But what exactly is the content fsimage, edits log and block reports? What things are updated in these three things say when a file is created or deleted?

Please explain with clear difference.